# Facebook login with Parse in iOS9 and Swift2

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to login with Facebook with Parse in iOS9 but the application keep opening Safari instead of Facebook app in real device. and even in Safari when I try to use the keyboard to enter the email and password of Facebook account the page reload so it's impossible to login and give the permission to the app. The user should open safari and login first in Facebook then open my app and then give permission. I think it's not the best user experience since the user have already a Facebook app.

I have followed all the steps I will list them here:

1. Add Fraleworks

   [image]
2. Link Binaries

[image]

1. Updaded info.plist

   ```
   <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
           <array>
               <string>fb907580375984874</string>
           </array>
       </dict>
   </array>
   <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
   <string>1</string>
   <key>FacebookAppID</key>
   <string>907580375984874</string>
   <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
   <string>Appname</string>
   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
   <array>
       <string>fbapi</string>
       <string>fbapi20130214</string>
       <string>fbapi20130410</string>
       <string>fbapi20130702</string>
       <string>fbapi20131010</string>
       <string>fbapi20131219</string>
       <string>fbapi20140410</string>
       <string>fbapi20140116</string>
       <string>fbapi20150313</string>
       <string>fbapi20150629</string>
       <string>fbauth</string>
       <string>fbauth2</string>
       <string>fb-messenger-api20140430</string>
   </array>
   <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
   <true/>
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
           <key>akamaihd.net</key>
           <dict>
               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
               <false/>
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
               <true/>
           </dict>
           <key>facebook.com</key>
           <dict>
               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
               <false/>
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
               <true/>
           </dict>
           <key>fbcdn.net</key>
           <dict>
               <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
               <false/>
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
               <true/>
           </dict>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```

   4. App Delegate

      ```
       import UIKit
       import Parse
       import FBSDKCoreKit
       import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

       @UIApplicationMain
       class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

      var window: UIWindow?

      func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
          Parse.setApplicationId("appID", clientKey: "MyKey")
          PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)   
          return true
      }

      func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
          return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url,sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
      }

      func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) { 
          FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
      }
      ```

      }
2. Login code:

   ```
   @IBAction func loginButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

   if let _ = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() {

      print("connected already")

   } else {

       PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_birthday" , "user_education_history","user_photos"]) {
           (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
           if let user = user {
               if user.isNew {
                   print("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
               } else {
                   print("User logged in through Facebook!")  
               }
           } else {
               print("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

Using a webview to log users in is now the default behaviour of the Facebook SDK for iOS 9 and according to Facebook team, this approach gives a better user experience as it avoids the additional dialogues being shown between app transitions.

> In apps that use the newest SDK (v4.6 and v3.24), we will surface a
>   flow using Safari View Controller (SVC) instead of fast-app-switching
>   (FAS) because of additional dialog interstitials that add extra steps
>   to the login process in FAS on iOS 9. Additionally, data that we've
>   seen from more than 250 apps indicate that this is the best experience
>   for people in the long run

[Read more on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/)